# Pass function to another function by pointer and by name

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm learning function pointers and this example from wiki:

```
int add(int first, int second)
{
    return first + second;
}

int subtract(int first, int second)
{
    return first - second;
}

int operation(int first, int second, int (*functocall)(int, int))
{
    return (*functocall)(first, second);
}

int main()
{
    int  a, b;
    int  (*plus)(int, int) = add;
    a = operation(7, 5, plus);
    b = operation(20, a, subtract);
    cout << "a = " << a << " and b = " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As I can see there `plus` is a pointer to function `add` and it's passed to function operation. It's clear. But what about `subtract`.

Why pointer is not used for it? What is the difference between 2 methods? Is it `c++` specific?

Comment: _Why pointer is not used for it?_ - Maybe for show, that you can call function without declaring a pointer?

Comment: function name is const function pointer which can not be left value.

Comment: It's clear. In that case what is the difference? Is it syntactic sugar? What is prefered way?

Comment: @viakondratiuk It depends on what you need. Declaring a function pointer variable makes it possible to change the function being called at runtime (e.g. if we consider your code, you could have two ways of making addition, and you could switch between the two functions by just changing the value of the `plus` pointer, without having to modify your call to operation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152167/why-is-using-the-function-name-as-a-function-pointer-equivalent-to-applying-the

Comment: Perl also has function references, but they are called subroutine references and they work very similarly to C. 

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, a function can be automatically converted to a function pointer, so the following are equivalent:

```
b = operation(20, a, subtract);
b = operation(20, a, &subtract);
```

Since `&substract` has thecorrect type(`int  (*)(int, int)`), the code compiles and works as expected.

> Is it c++ specific?

Can't really answer this, since there might be other languages that allow this. I'm more than sure there are.

Comment: Actually the same implicit conversion also happens in the definition of `plus`, which without it would have to be end in `= &add;`.

Answer (score 3):

### Why pointer is not used for `substract`?

In fact, all the function name is a pointer in its corresponding live scope. Here, in your code, when you define the function `substract()`, `add()`.

You also defined two variable named `substract` and `add`, which type is function pointer: `int (*)(int, int)`. so you can declare a new function pointer `plus`, and assign `add` to it. All the three variables is all pointer.

The following is the assembly code generated by `clang++`, which could give you a detail explanation. I have removed all the un-relevant code. The function name is a bit ugly to read, this is because of the [C++ name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), you can just ignore the capital chars and digits to easily understand the name.

function `add()`:

```
    .text
    .globl  _Z3addii
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z3addii,@function
_Z3addii:                               # @_Z3addii
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movl    %edi, -4(%rsp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rsp)
    movl    -4(%rsp), %esi
    addl    -8(%rsp), %esi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    ret
.Ltmp6:
    .size   _Z3addii, .Ltmp6-_Z3addii
    .cfi_endproc
```

function `substract`:

```
    .globl  _Z8subtractii
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z8subtractii,@function
_Z8subtractii:                          # @_Z8subtractii
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movl    %edi, -4(%rsp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rsp)
    movl    -4(%rsp), %esi
    subl    -8(%rsp), %esi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    ret
.Ltmp7:
    .size   _Z8subtractii, .Ltmp7-_Z8subtractii
    .cfi_endproc
```

The `_Z3addii` and `_Z8subtractii` label give the start point of the two function, which also is an address that point to the start of the function.

I have add some comments in the code to show how the function pointer works, which started with `###`.

function `main`:

```
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp16:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp17:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp18:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    $7, %edi
    movl    $5, %esi
    leaq    _Z3addii, %rax  ### Here, the assembly just load the label of _Z3addii, not a plus related variable, so in fact they are  the same type.
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx  ### move the value of the function pointer to the rdx register.
    callq   _Z9operationiiPFiiiE
    movl    $20, %edi
    leaq    _Z8subtractii, %rdx  ### Here, just load the label -f _Z8subsractii, which is the value of the function pointer substract. move it directly to rdx register.
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
    callq   _Z9operationiiPFiiiE
    leaq    _ZSt4cout, %rdi
    leaq    .L.str, %rsi
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    callq   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSolsEi
    leaq    .L.str1, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movl    -12(%rbp), %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSolsEi
    leaq    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    movl    $0, %ecx
    movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.Ltmp19:
    .size   main, .Ltmp19-main
    .cfi_endproc
```

In the above `main` function assebly, we saw that all the function pointer value is moved to the register `rdx`. Here in the following operation function:

function `operation()`:

```
    .globl  _Z9operationiiPFiiiE
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z9operationiiPFiiiE,@function
_Z9operationiiPFiiiE:                   # @_Z9operationiiPFiiiE
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp10:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp11:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp12:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi
    movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
    callq   *%rdx  ### directly jump to the address, which is the value of the rdx register.
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.Ltmp13:
    .size   _Z9operationiiPFiiiE, .Ltmp13-_Z9operationiiPFiiiE
    .cfi_endproc
```

So, we can see from the assembly that,  the variable `substract`, `add`, `plus` in your given code are all pointers, and comes from the label of the start point of the function.

### What is the difference between the two method?

Since the `plus`, `add` and `substract` are all the same type function pointers, just like Luchian Grigore says, they are the same.

From the above assembly code, we can also find out that, the two method are absolutely the same method call, without any difference.

### Is it `C++` specified?

#### `C` family languages

and some other derived languages, like `obj-c` support function pointers directly.

#### Java language

In Java, there is such a concept named function pointers, but an `class` which `implemnts` an  interface`  could achieve the same goal as function pointer.

For example:
you could define an interface first:

```
interface StringFunction {
  int function(String param);
}
```

and then define an function that could accept objects that implements the interface:

```
public void takingMethod(StringFunction sf) {
   //stuff
   int output = sf.function(input);
   // more stuff
}
```

And then you could define different classes that `implements` interface `StringFunction`, and use it as an parameter of `takingMethod()`

#### Python

In Python, function name is just a type of variable, and you could directly use it, like the following ways:

```
def plus_1(x):
    return x + 1

def minus_1(x):
    return x - 1

func_map = {'+' : plus_1, '-' : minus_1}

func_map['+'](3)  # returns plus_1(3) ==> 4
func_map['-'](3)  # returns minus_1(3) ==> 2
```

#### Ruby

Ruby also have some similar ways: [Function pointer in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095841/function-pointer-in-ruby)

Comment: *"You also defined two variable named `substract` and `add`, which type is function pointer: `int (*)(int, int)`. so you can declare a new function pointer `plus`, and assign `add` to it. All the three variables is all pointer."* - No, that's wrong. `add` and `subtract` are functions. They can (and often will) implicitly convert to function pointers, but they *are no pointers*, in the same way an array is not a pointer, even if often decaying to one. Of course in the machine functions are memory addresses in the same way like variables are, but since when did the standard care about this.